# Selective reduction of aromatic nitro group

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction, nitro-compounds

In the following compound, is it possible to selectively reduce the aromatic nitro group to an amine, as shown in the reaction?

[image]

I fear that the methods usually used to reduce aromatic nitro compounds, such as Fe/HCl or catalytic hydrogenation, will also reduce the aliphatic NO2. Is there any reaction that could achieve reduction of only the aromatic one? Or, is it possible to somehow protect the nitro group from reduction?

Comment: What does Skyrim do to user's nicks...

Comment: While I cannot find you a reference, I think SnCl.2H2O in refluxing EtOAc will do this selectively as described here  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403901800411. Sodium hydrosulfite in EtOH is also a possibility